# Free, invalid pointer

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays, strtok

I have a program, that splits strings based on the delimiter. I have also, 2 other functions, one that prints the returned array and another that frees the array.

My program prints the array and returns an error when the free array method is called. Below is the full code.

```
#include "stringsplit.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

/* Split string by another string, return split parts + NULL in array.
 *
 * Parameters: 
 *  str: the string to split
 *  split: the string to split str with
 *
 * Returns:
 *  A dynamically reserved array of dynamically reserved string parts.
 *
 * For example called with "Test string split" and " ",
 * returns ["Test", "string", "split", NULL].
 * Or called with "Another - test" and " - ",
 * returns ["Another", "test", NULL].
 */

unsigned long int getNofTokens(const char *string) {
  char *stringCopy;
  unsigned long int stringLength;
  unsigned long int count = 0;

  stringLength = (unsigned)strlen(string);
  stringCopy = malloc((stringLength + 1) * sizeof(char));
  strcpy(stringCopy, string);

  if (strtok(stringCopy, " \t") != NULL) {
    count++;
    while (strtok(NULL, " \t") != NULL)
        count++;
  }

  free(stringCopy);
  return count;
}

char **split_string(const char *str, const char *split) {
    unsigned long int count = getNofTokens(str);
    char **result;
    result = malloc(sizeof(char *) * count + 1);
    
    char *tmp = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(str));
    strcpy(tmp, str);
    
    char *token = strtok(tmp, split);
    
    int idx = 0;
    while (token != NULL) {
        result[idx++] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, split);
    }
    
    return result;
}

void print_split_string(char **split_string) {
    for (int i = 0; split_string[i] != NULL; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", split_string[i]);
    }
}

void free_split_string(char **split_string) {
    for (int i = 0; split_string[i] != NULL; i++) {
        char *currentPointer = split_string[i];
        free(currentPointer);
    }

    free(split_string);
}
```

Also, do I need to explicitly add `\0` at the end of the array or does `strtok` add it automatically?

Comment: You must only `free` pointers that you `malloc`ed (or `calloc`ed or `realloc`ed or `strdup`ed)

Comment: @user253751 basically, you should only pass those pointers which are returned by allocator functions.

Comment: and actually, you don't free pointers, you free objects

Comment: The input for free_split_string is the array returned by the split_string. Which I have made using malloc. So I'm confused as to why that'd cause an issue?

Comment: *"Also, do I need to explicitly add "\0" at the end of the array or does strtok add it automatically?"* - That's a typical thing that you read about in the documentation.

Comment: @cybermon It's not the `free(spit_string);` that is the issue. It is the `free(currentPointer);` (equivalent to `free(split_string[i]);`) that is the issue. The `split_string[i]` values were not returned by the memory allocation functions, they were returned by `strtok` and point to some byte _within_ a memory allocation. You can only free using a pointer to the _beginning_ of a memory allocation.

Comment: It is strange that you do not pass the string of delimiters `split` from `split_string` to `getNoOfTokens`, but use a possibly different, fixed string of delimiters within `getNoOfTokens`. That means `split_string` will only get the correct number of tokens when `split` matches the set of delimiters used within `getNoOfTokens` and is a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: @cyberbemon free_split_string doesn't only free its input though, does it? It also frees all the pointers in its input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some problems in your code:

- **[Major]** the function `getNofTokens()` does not take the separator string as an argument, it counts the number of words separated by blanks, potentially returning an inconsistent count to its caller.
- **[Major]** the size allocated in `result = malloc(sizeof(char *) * count + 1);` is incorrect: it should be:

  ```
    result = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (count + 1));
  ```

  Storing the trailing `NULL` pointer will write beyond the end of the allocated space.
- **[Major]** storing the said `NULL` terminator at the end of the array is indeed necessary, as the block of memory returned by `malloc()` is uninitialized.
- **[Major]** the copy of the string allocated and parsed by `split_string` cannot be safely freed because the pointer `tmp` is not saved anywhere. The pointer to the first token will be different from `tmp` in 2 cases: if the string contains only delimiters (no token found) or if the string starts with a delimiter (the initial delimiters will be skipped). In order to simplify the code and make it reliable, each token could be duplicated and `tmp` should be freed. In fact your `free_split_string()` function relies on this behavior. With the current implementation, the behavior is undefined.
- **[Minor]** you use `unsigned long` and `int` inconsistently for strings lengths and array index variables. For consistency, you should use `size_t` for both.
- **[Remark]** you should allocate string copies with `strdup()`. If this POSIX standard function is not available on your system, write a simple implementation.
- **[Major]** you never test for memory allocation failure. This is OK for testing purposes and throw away code, but such potential failures should always be accounted for in production code.
- **[Remark]** `strtok()` is a tricky function to use: it modifies the source string and keeps a hidden static state that makes it non-reentrant. You should avoid using this function although in this particular case it performs correctly, but if the caller of `split_string` or `getNofTokens` relied on this hidden state being preserved, it would get unexpected behavior.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "stringsplit.h"

/* Split string by another string, return split parts + NULL in array.
 *
 * Parameters: 
 *  str: the string to split
 *  split: the string to split str with
 *
 * Returns:
 *  A dynamically reserved array of dynamically reserved string parts.
 *
 * For example called with "Test string split" and " ",
 * returns ["Test", "string", "split", NULL].
 * Or called with "Another - test" and " - ",
 * returns ["Another", "test", NULL].
 */

size_t getNofTokens(const char *string, const char *split) {
    char *tmp = strdup(string);
    size_t count = 0;

    if (strtok(tmp, split) != NULL) {
        count++;
        while (strtok(NULL, split) != NULL)
            count++;
    }
    free(tmp);
    return count;
}

char **split_string(const char *str, const char *split) {
    size_t count = getNofTokens(str, split);
    char **result = malloc(sizeof(*result) * (count + 1));
    
    char *tmp = strdup(str);
    char *token = strtok(tmp, split);
    
    size_t idx = 0;
    while (token != NULL && idx < count) {
        result[idx++] = strdup(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, split);
    }
    result[idx] = NULL;
    
    free(tmp);
    return result;
}

void print_split_string(char **split_string) {
    for (size_t i = 0; split_string[i] != NULL; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", split_string[i]);
    }
}

void free_split_string(char **split_string) {
    for (size_t i = 0; split_string[i] != NULL; i++) {
        free(split_string[i]);
    }
    free(split_string);
}
```

Here is an alternative without `strtok()` and without intermediary allocations:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "stringsplit.h"

size_t getNofTokens(const char *str, const char *split) {
    size_t count = 0;
    size_t pos = 0, len;

    for (pos = 0;; pos += len) {
        pos += strspn(str + pos, split);  // skip delimiters
        len = strcspn(str + pos, split);  // parse token
        if (len == '\0')
            break;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

char **split_string(const char *str, const char *split) {
    size_t count = getNofTokens(str, split);
    char **result = malloc(sizeof(*result) * (count + 1));
    size_t pos, len, idx;

    for (pos = 0, idx = 0; idx < count; pos += len, idx++) {
        pos += strspn(str + pos, split);  // skip delimiters
        len = strcspn(str + pos, split);  // parse token
        if (len == '\0')
            break;
        result[idx] = strndup(str + pos, len);
    }
    result[idx] = NULL;
    return result;
}

void print_split_string(char **split_string) {
    for (size_t i = 0; split_string[i] != NULL; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", split_string[i]);
    }
}

void free_split_string(char **split_string) {
    for (size_t i = 0; split_string[i] != NULL; i++) {
        free(split_string[i]);
    }
    free(split_string);
}
```

**EDIT** After re-reading the specification in your comment, there seems to be some potential confusion as to the semantics of the `split` argument:

- if `split` is a set of delimiters, the above code does the job. And the examples will be split as expected.
- if `split` is an actual string to match explicitly, the above code only works by coincidence on the examples given in the comment.

To implement the latter semantics, you should use `strstr()` to search for the `split` substring in both `getNofTokens` and `split_string`.

Here is an example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "stringsplit.h"

/* Split string by another string, return split parts + NULL in array.
 *
 * Parameters:
 *  str: the string to split
 *  split: the string to split str with
 *
 * Returns:
 *  A dynamically reserved array of dynamically reserved string parts.
 *
 * For example called with "Test string split" and " ",
 * returns ["Test", "string", "split", NULL].
 * Or called with "Another - test" and " - ",
 * returns ["Another", "test", NULL].
 */

size_t getNofTokens(const char *str, const char *split) {
    const char *p;
    size_t count = 1;
    size_t len = strlen(split);
    
    if (len == 0)
        return strlen(str);
    for (p = str; (p = strstr(p, split)) != NULL; p += len)
        count++;
    return count;
}

char **split_string(const char *str, const char *split) {
    size_t count = getNofTokens(str, split);
    char **result = malloc(sizeof(*result) * (count + 1));
    size_t len = strlen(split);
    size_t idx;
    const char *p = str;

    for (idx = 0; idx < count; idx++) {
        const char *q = strstr(p, split);
        if (q == NULL) {
            q = p + strlen(p);
        } else
        if (q == p && *q != '\0') {
            q++;
        }
        result[idx] = strndup(p, q - p);
        p = q + len;
    }
    result[idx] = NULL;
    return result;
}

void print_split_string(char **split_string) {
    for (size_t i = 0; split_string[i] != NULL; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", split_string[i]);
    }
}

void free_split_string(char **split_string) {
    for (size_t i = 0; split_string[i] != NULL; i++) {
        free(split_string[i]);
    }
    free(split_string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When debugging, take note of values that you got from `malloc`, `strdup`, etc. Let's call these values "the active set". It's just a name, so that we can refer to them. You get a pointer from those functions, you mentally add it to the active set. When you call `free`, you can *only* pass values from the active set, and after free returns, you mentally remove them from the set. Any other use of `free` is invalid and a bug.

You can easily find this out by putting breakpoints after all memory allocations, so that you can write down the pointer values, and then breakpoints on all frees, so that you can see if one of those pointer values got passed to free - since, again, to do otherwise is to misuse `free`.

This can be done also using "printf" debugging. Like this:

```
char *buf = malloc(...); // or strdup, or ...
fprintf(stderr, "+++ Alloc %8p\n", buf);
```

And then whenever you have free, do it again:

```
fprintf(stderr, "--- Free  %8p\n", ptr);
free(ptr);
```

In the output of the program, you must be able to match every `+++` with `---`. If you see any `---` with a value that wasn't earlier listed with a `+++`, there's your problem: that's the buggy invocation of free :)

I suggest using `fprintf(stderr, ...` instead of `printf(...`, since the former is typically unbuffered, so if your program crashes, you won't miss any output. `printf` is buffered on some architectures (and not buffered on others - so much for consistency).

Comment: wow! you have become quite clear about your priorities :)